# How to make a correct SQL query for currencies rates tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, connected via FOREIGN KEY

Currencies table:

```
CREATE TABLE Currencies
            (id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            mark varchar(3) NOT NULL,
            english_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            deutsch_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            russian_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            chinese_name varchar(50) NOT NULL);
```

In Currencies table mark stays for symbols, that represent currency, e.g. 'USD'.

CoreRates table:

```
CREATE TABLE CoreRates
            (id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            datetime datetime NOT NULL,
            base_currency_id int NOT NULL,
            target_currency_id int NOT NULL,
            rate float(40,20) NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT rate_info UNIQUE(datetime,base_currency_id,target_currency_id),
            FOREIGN KEY (base_currency_id) REFERENCES Currencies(id),
            FOREIGN KEY (target_currency_id) REFERENCES Currencies(id));
```

base_currency_id always equals to id of a currency, which mark = "EUR".

I need to get rate of given currency (by mark - its an input from python script, e.g. 'USD') to another given currency (by mark - its an input from python script, e.g. 'CNY') for a chosen period (two datetime string are given, e.g. '2020-07-25', '2020-07-28'). And I need to put this data into DataMarts3 table:

```
CREATE TABLE DataMart3
            (datetime datetime NOT NULL,
            base_mark varchar(3) NOT NULL,
            target_mark varchar(3) NOT NULL,
            rate float(40,20) NOT NULL)
```

What is the correct SQL query for this?

I have tried this one:

```
INSERT INTO DataMart3 (
            DataMart3.datetime,
            DataMart3.base_mark,
            DataMart3.target_mark,
            DataMart3.rate
        )
SELECT CoreRates.datetime,
               'USD',
               'RUB',
               (SELECT (1 / CoreRates.rate) FROM CoreRates WHERE CoreRates.target_currency_id = (SELECT Currencies.id FROM Currencies WHERE Currencies.mark = 'USD') AND CoreRates.base_currency_id = (SELECT Currencies.id FROM Currencies WHERE Currencies.mark = 'EUR'))
               * 
               (SELECT (CoreRates.rate) FROM CoreRates WHERE CoreRates.base_currency_id = (SELECT Currencies.id FROM Currencies WHERE Currencies.mark = 'EUR') AND CoreRates.target_currency_id = (SELECT Currencies.id FROM Currencies WHERE Currencies.mark = 'CNY'))
FROM CoreRates
WHERE '2021-06-25' <= CoreRates.datetime AND CoreRates.datetime <= '2021-08-25'
```

but MySQL, which I'm working with says "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Update:
Some seed data for tables:
For Currencies table:

```
INSERT INTO `Currencies` (`id`, `mark`, `english_name`, `deutsch_name`, `russian_name`, `chinese_name`) VALUES
(1, 'USD', 'Dollar', 'Dollar', 'Доллар', '美元'),
(2, 'EUR', 'Euro', 'Euro', 'Евро', '歐元'),
(3, 'RUB', 'Ruble', 'Rubel', 'Рубль', '盧布'),
(4, 'CNY', 'Yuan', 'Yuan', 'Юань', '元');
```

For CoreRates table:

```
INSERT INTO `CoreRates` (`id`, `datetime`, `base_currency_id`, `target_currency_id`, `rate`) VALUES
(86, '2021-07-25 22:55:04', 2, 1, 1.1775000095),
(87, '2021-07-25 22:55:04', 2, 2, 1.0000000000),
(88, '2021-07-25 22:55:04', 2, 3, 86.8230056763),
(89, '2021-07-25 22:55:04', 2, 4, 7.6318497658),
(93, '2021-07-25 23:50:04', 2, 1, 1.1775000095),
(94, '2021-07-25 23:50:04', 2, 2, 1.0000000000),
(95, '2021-07-25 23:50:04', 2, 3, 86.8230056763),
(96, '2021-07-25 23:50:04', 2, 4, 7.6318449974),
(100, '2021-07-26 00:45:04', 2, 4, 7.6292119026),
(101, '2021-07-26 00:45:04', 2, 2, 1.0000000000),
(102, '2021-07-26 00:45:04', 2, 3, 86.7930831909),
(103, '2021-07-26 00:45:04', 2, 1, 1.1770939827),
(107, '2021-07-26 09:00:04', 2, 4, 7.6418271065),
(108, '2021-07-26 09:00:04', 2, 2, 1.0000000000),
(109, '2021-07-26 09:00:04', 2, 3, 87.1985549927),
(110, '2021-07-26 09:00:04', 2, 1, 1.1783670187),
(114, '2021-07-26 09:55:03', 2, 4, 7.6384859085),
(115, '2021-07-26 09:55:03', 2, 2, 1.0000000000),
(116, '2021-07-26 09:55:03', 2, 3, 87.2046127319),
(117, '2021-07-26 09:55:03', 2, 1, 1.1774890423);
```

Comment: Provide some sample data as INSERT INTO (3-5 rows) and desired output for this data.

Comment: Hi @mandaren : You can use MIN or MAX inside subquery for avoiding more than 1 row.